# If $A$ is dense, prove that $f(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus

> Let $A$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. That is, a set such that every open interval contains an element of $A$. Assume $f$ is a **continuous** function on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My approach to this question was showing maybe that a dense set of $\mathbb{R}$ is in some must be $\mathbb{R}$. Otherwise if it were some smaller interval the then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ may not necessarily be true. But how do I show that $A = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: you want that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @user251257 You mean in the condition of the problem?

Comment: This follows from a general property:

If two continuous functions agree on a dense subset of a metric space, they agree on the entire space.

In this case, $f$ is identically $0$ on $A$, that is, $f$ is equal to the $0$ function, and thus it is equal to $0$ on $\mathbb R$

Comment: @user19405892 yes

Comment: This fails without continuity, just consider the indicator function on $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Yes, otherwise $\mathbb{1_Q}$ is a counterexample (as, for that matter, is $\mathbb{1_{R \setminus Q}}$).

Comment: Otherwise, a counterexample is: $A$ the set of rational numbers, $$f(x) = \cases{1 & if $x$ is irrational\cr 0 & if $x$ is rational\cr}$$

Comment: Come on, doesn't anyone have any original ideas? :-P

Comment: How does one prove this?

Comment: for every $x\in\mathbb R$ there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $A$ with limit $x$. Now, what is $f(x)$?

Comment: @user251257 What do you mean?

Comment: @user19405892 it is the beginning of a proof using sequential continuity...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this is tagged as calculus, let's do $\epsilon$-$\delta$ and contradiction.

Assume that there is an $x \notin A$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$. Now, take $\epsilon = \frac{|f(x)|}2$. Then the definition of continuity of $f$ at the point $x$ gives us a $\delta > 0$. But the open, non-empty interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ contains some point $a \in A$ (since $A$ is dense), and we have $f(a) = 0$. This means that
$$
|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x)| = 2\epsilon \not < \epsilon
$$
even though $|x-a| < \delta$, which contradicts the continuity of $f$.

Comment: I am a little confused by your $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ argument.

Comment: @user19405892 The definition of continuity says "for every $y$ with $|x-y| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$". This means exactly the same as "for every $y \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon$" (the absolute value notation is easier to carry over to more general settings, like $\Bbb R^n$, which is why that's the one typically used). I have shown that there is at least one $y$, namely $a$, which is in said interval, but does _not_ fulfill $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$, as it should according to the definition of continuity. Therefore $f$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: So you showed there does not exist a $\delta$?

Comment: @user19405892 If you wish to put a more explicit contradiction into this, then yes.

Comment: But that's what you showed, right, that no such delta could exist.

Comment: @user19405892 Yes, I have shown that the existence of an $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ is incompatible with the existence of a $\delta$ that fulfills the definition of continuity at $x$ for some specific $\epsilon$ that I chose.

Comment: What about the case "Prove that if $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in A$, then $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in R$"?

Comment: @user19405892 Examine the function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, and what $h(x) = 0$ signifies with regards to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: Wait don't we just show it the same way as you did? We are just substituting in $h(x)$.

Comment: @Artur: I don't think you have read your own argument very carefully: *"... gives us a $\delta > 0$"* such that what?

Comment: @RobArthan Writing out the definition of continuity would double the length of my answer (thus make it less readable), and it can be found in any textbook, more or less verbatim. In addition to that, most people who read this will know the definition by heart, or at least have the sense to look it up. Isn't it enough for you that I _explicitly_ state that I use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ in the first sentence of my answer, and later say that it is _the definition of continuity_ that gives me a $\delta$, when the only defined entities so far are a function $f$, a point $x$ and an $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: There is no need for you to write out the definition of continuity. But clear exposition requires you to say what is special about your $\delta > 0$ in this argument.

Comment: @RobArthan But explicitly stating "gives us a $\delta$ such that for any $y\in \Bbb R$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$" _is_ basically writing out the definition of continuity. What is special about the $\delta$ is that it is provided by the definition of continuity. I am under the conviction that writing out the rest would clutter more than it would clarify.

Comment: @Artur: OK. I would argue that writing out what we want the estimates we get from the definition of continuity to achieve is much clearer than saying "let's do $\epsilon-\delta$" and leaving the reader to work out what that implies. Let's agree to differ.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and take $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset A$ with $a_n \to x$. Then, $f(a_n) = 0$ for all $n$. By continuity, $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$.

This can be generalized! For any metric space $X$ (or Hausdorff topological space; if you don't know what these are, replace the term "metric space $X$" with $\mathbb{R}$) and $A\subset X$ dense, if two functions $f$ and $g$ agree on $A$ then they agree on all of $X$.

Comment: Since you went as general as Hausdorff topological spaces, I want to point out that there are maps between Hausdorff topological spaces that are not inverse-image-of-opens continuous (which is the topological generalisation of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuous) but are sequentially continuous. However, in that case the domain space is not first-countable, so specifically it is not metrizable.

Comment: Yes, thank you.