# If $A$ is dense, prove that $f(x) \geq g(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Let $A$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. That is, a set such that every open interval contains an element of $A$. Assume $f$ and $g$ are  continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x \in A$, then $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Can $\geq$ be replaced by $>$?

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677725/if-a-is-dense-prove-that-fx-0). I am wondering if we can use the same strategy and prove this by contradiction. Or else do we have to prove it using the intermediate value theorem or continuity $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Comment: Counter-example: $A=\mathbb{Q}$, $f(x)=0$, and $g(x)=\mathbf{1}_{A^c}(x)$. Was $g$ supposed to be continuous too, maybe?

Comment: Yes sorry about that. Also what does the bold $1$ you drew mean?

Comment: Contradiction is a good idea. First prove that if $f(x)=g(x)$ on some dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)=g(x)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ by using contradiction. I believe it follows from that.

Comment: @user19405892: bold 1 is indicator function (check Wikipedia for examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be in $\mathbb{R}$, then there is a sequence $\{x_{n}\}\subset A$
such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$. Therefore, 
$$
f(x)=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_{n})\geq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(x_{n})=g(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n})=g(x).
$$