# $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=-1$, and $f(2)=1$ implies the existence of $a,b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f((a,b))<0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f$ be "differentiable". $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=-1$, and $f(2)=1$.

We can prove that there exist real numbers $a,b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Question: can the "differentiable" requirement be relaxed to "continuous"?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: Just as an observation, note that if it is not required that $a\not=b$ then taking $a=b=0$ the result follows, since $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in]0,0[=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Deif $f(\emptyset)<0$?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I might need to be more rigorous, to rule out cases similar to Weierstrass function or the topologist's sine curve

Comment: @dodo No. For each element in the empty set $f(x)<0$. Since there is no element in the empty set you can say whatever you want about properties of "its elements". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, by IVT there exists $x \in (1,2)$ such that $f(x)=0.$

Now define $x_0:= \sup\{ x\in [0,1): f(x)=0 \}\ $ and $x_1:= \inf\{ x\in (1,2): f(x)=0 \}.\ $ We have two possibilities:

1. $f(x_0) \neq 0.\ $ As a consequence of $\sup,$ this implies the existence of a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ (with $\ y_n\neq x_0\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}),\ $ such that $\ \displaystyle y_n\to {x_0}^-\ $ and $\ f(y_n) = 0\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}.$ But then it is not difficult to show that this contradicts the continuity of $f$ at $x_0,$ for example using an argument [like this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1677735/29156). So we see that this possibility, $f(x_0) \neq 0,\ $ is actually
   an impossibility. Therefore the other possibility must be true:
2. $f(x_0) = 0.\ $ Then since $f(1)=-1\neq 0,\ $ it follows that $x_0<1.\ $ Now in this scenario, suppose further that $\ \exists\ y\in  (x_0,1)\ $ such that $f(y)\geq 0.$ Then by IVT $\ \exists\ y'\in [y,1)\ $ such that $f(y')=0.$ But since $y'>x_0,$ this contradicts the fact that $x_0\ $ is the greatest $t\in [0,1)\ $ with $f(t)=0.$ This contradiction means we can reject our supposition that $\ \exists\ y\in  (x_0,1)\ $ such that $f(y)\geq 0.$ In other words, we conclude that for all $y\in (x_0,1),\ f(y) < 0.$

In summary, $x_0<1,\ f(x_0) = 0\ $ and for all $y\in (x_0,1),\ f(y) < 0.$

By applying a similar argument for $f(x_1)$ on $(1,x_1],$ we can deduce that $x_1>1,\ f(x_1) = 0\ $ and for all $y\in (1,x_1),\ f(y) < 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ being differentiable implies continunity, and we know that $f(1)<0$ and $f(2)>0$, from the intermediate value theorem, we know that there exists $f(k) = 0$ where $k \in [1,2]$.

Now, we will (very unrigorously) put our pen down at $x=1$ and trace the function towards the positive infinity direction. We will keep on tracing until we cross the $x$-axis. This will always happen, since we are at least guaranteed the $k$. We will prove that, apart from the very ends, that this line segment is always negative.

FSOC, assume that there is a point along that tracing (not at $k$) that achieves a value of $0$. This is a contradiction as we assumed that we end the curve at the very first time we cross the $x$-axis, but it is shown here that we cross the $x$-axis earlier.

Now, if that point is positive, we can apply the intermediate value theorem with the point $f(1)$ and again, with similar reasoning, we find that we have crossed the $x$-axis already.

Thus, the curve we have traced is (apart from $k$) is all below the $x$-axis.

Now, similarly, we will trace again, starting at $f(1)$ and this time heading towards the negative infinity direction. We are bound to hit the $x$-axis at $f(0)=0$, so this process won't continue indefinitely. Via similar reasoning, we can find a $K$ such that $f(K)=0$ and $k \in [0,1]$ and prove that the curve drawn (apart from the leftmost point) is completely below the $x$-axis.

Alternatively, we have proved that the two curves $(K,1]$ and $[1,k)$ are all under the $x$-axis. Thus, we have that the curve $(K,k)$ is completely under the $x$-axis. Moreover, we also have that $f(K)=f(k)=0$, and so we have found the two real numbers and have (very unrigorously) proved that their properties are true.

Comment: We might need to be more rigorous, to rule out cases similar to Weierstrass function or the topologist's sine curve